# Datas no python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como posso obter varias datas diferentes na mesma run do meu script?
Eu tenho o meu script feito desta forma:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
Time = '{:%H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=6))
```

Mas o script chama esse string mais que uma vez mas em vez de vir resultados diferentes vem sempre o mesmo. É possivel fazer com que venha sempre resultados diferentes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mas `Time` é uma variável (aliás, variáveis em python, por convenção, devem usar letras minúsculas), daí seu conteúdo terá sempre o mesmo valor (no caso sempre a mesma *string* definida no começo do programa).

O que você precisa fazer é criar uma função para isto, algo como:

```py
def time_plus_six_hours():
    return "{:%H:%M:%S}".format(datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=6))
```

E chamá-la sempre que necessário...

```py
print(time_plus_six_hours())
```

Comment: Por que elas **devem** começar com letra minúscula?

Comment: Opa, corrigindo... faltou o _não_ na frase.

Comment: Ficou ainda mais estranha a afirmação :S É convenção deixar as variáveis com letras minúsculas, mas isso não é obrigatório, então o "deve"  ficou bem esquisito

Comment: Redação melhorada.

Comment: Acabei por conseguir resolver sozinho !